# What does an unquoted shell variable allow?

Tags: nginx

I have the following dash *(dash is the default Ubuntu shell instead of bash)* code which run in a server side script. This script is not run by the root user.

```
git clone -b $DEFAULT_BRANCH file://$target $target
```

Where`$target`is completely sanitized with`\`but not`$DEFAULT_BRANCH`. I have full control of`$DEFAULT_BRANCH`as long as it is a valid git branch name, which mean it :

- needs to start with`refs/`;
- does not contains ASCII characters in the range 0–32 (so no spaces);
- does not contain `@` or `..` (but it can contain `$()\|<>[]{}/*#!?`);
- ’s length is lesser than 65535-4.
- the branch file can only contains a 40 bytes base64 sha1

Things I thought about so far:

- I can’t glob since paths needs to start with `refs/` and it can’t contain `..`.
- Expand the command line list twice.
  Result:`$*` stay`$*`even without quotes.

So is the design choice of not sanitizing and quoting`$DEFAULT_BRANCH`harmless?

Comment: The server will return an http 500 error if`$BRANCH`doesn’t exist in the git repository.

Comment: So branch could contain syntax characters like semicolon and percent?

Comment: @NeilSmithline yes of course. This means it can also contains $ `` () \ | < > [] {} / * # ! ? but not spaces.

Answer (score 4):

In general, `$DEFAULT_BRANCH` (with no surrounding quotes) is the “split+glob” operator. What it does is:

1. Take the value of the variable `DEFAULT_BRANCH` (or the empty string if the variable is unset). This is a string.
2. Split the string at each whitespace sequence (assuming the default value of `IFS`). This produces a list of strings.
3. For every element in the list, if it contains a wildcard character (at least one of `\*?`) then it is interpreted as a wildcard pattern ([glob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming))) and replaced by the list of matching file names. If there are no wildcards or if there are no matches, the element is unchanged. Thus the result is a list of strings (that is at least as long as the previous one).

Contrast with `"$DEFAULT_BRANCH"` (variable expansion in double quotes), which expands to the value of the variable `DEFAULT_BRANCH`, plain and simple.

If the value of the variable `DEFAULT_BRANCH` does not contains any whitespace or any of the characters `\[*?`, and the `IFS` variable is set to its default value, then `$DEFAULT_BRANCH` expands to the value of `DEFAULT_BRANCH`.

Provided that you've sanitized the value of the variable to contain only safe characters, and that you're sure that `IFS` hasn't been changed, leaving the variable unquoted is correct.

If the value of `DEFAULT_BRANCH` *can* contain wildcards then it's another story — your assertion that you “can't glob” does not follow. For example, the leading `refs/` prefix and the ban from `..` does not imply that `refs/.[.]/.[.]/.[.]/.[.]/etc/passwd` is banned. If you don't block wildcards, `DEFAULT_BRANCH` could refer to an arbitrary file. If your filter is `git check-ref-format`, it does block wildcards; I think it makes an unquoted `$DEFAULT_BRANCH` unexploitable.

In any case, leaving a variable unquoted is never *harmless*. Every time you see an unquoted variable, you need to worry about what makes it safe to leave it unquoted. This is a lot more expensive than writing those double quote characters in the first place. So any variable substitution (or command substitution, same thing) that's left unquoted without a clear need should be reported as a finding and gear your overall evaluation towards judgint the code as sloppy.

Note that there is another gotcha: leading dashes. A leading `-` in the argument to a command, in many contexts, causes the argument to be interpreted as an option. This can result in the command executing arbitrary code instead of processing a file. To protect against this, put any argument that comes from a variable after `--`, which means “stop processing options (and accept only operand arguments) from that point”. For example, if `myfile` has the value `-mfoo`, then `file -i "$myfile"` analyses its standard input based on the magic database file `foo`, whereas `file -i -- "$myfile"` analyses the file called `-mfoo` based on the default magic database.

In [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells), Stéphane Chazelas gives examples of exploits on scripts that don't properly.

In your case, `git clone -b $DEFAULT_BRANCH file://$target $target` is unsafe, both with respect to `DEFAULT_BRANCH` and with respect to `target`.  How exploitable this is depends on what files are present in the system (I don't know what means you have of injecting them).

You say that `DEFAULT_BRANCH` has to start with `refs/` and can't contain spaces, but can contain wildcard characters. Since it starts with `refs/`, option injection with a dash is impossible — even with wildcards, all matches will start with `refs/`. You might end up running `git clone` with more operands than it can cope with, which would result in an error. If you're able to create a directory called `refs` and a symbolic link inside it, then you may be able to enumerate files on the system, but I don't think you'll be able to read them as `git clone` will just stop and complain about extra arguments.

If `DEFAULT_BRANCH` could start with `-` then you could probably overwrite arbitrary files with values like `-u /path/to/file` and possibly even run arbitrary commands through `--config=…` (I'm not completely sure about that, `clone` isn't hook-rich).

As for `target`, apparently, it *can* start with `-`, so you can pass options that way. Try values of the form `-option=badvalue/path/to/file`: the part up to the first slash is effectively ignored in `file://$target`, which lets you specify an option with a value that ends in a valid path to a file. More options may be possible if you can inject files and craft an appropriate wildcard pattern.

You say that “`$target` is completely sanitized with `\`”. I don't know what you mean by that; it's impossible to “sanitize” a variable by adding backslashes to a value. Backslashes are only expanded in an unquoted expansion of there is at least one wildcard character. For example, `\bar` is expanded to `\bar`, not `bar`; only something like `\*z` becomes `*z`. The only way to protect a variable against expansion mishaps is to double-quote its use, you can't prepare for an unquoted expansion by massaging the value unless you make restrictive assumptions about what the value was in the first place.

Comment: I mean that if $target contains a`*`for example, a`\`will be inserted before it.

Comment: I’m not the author of the script. In the meantime, there’s no regex for doing it. You really can’t attempt anything on $target.

Comment: @user2284570 How about beginning with a dash? I'm not familiar enough with git but I'd be surprised if there was no way to cause some damage with an option. P.S. I deleted my previous command because the sanitization example I gave was too broken.

Comment: The dash would be escaped for $target and $DEFAULT_BRANCH can’t start with a dash.

Comment: @user2284570 I noticed that given your description of the sanitization of `DEFAULT_BRANCH`, you can perform a directory traversal. However, if the check is actually `git check-ref-format` then it is more stringent and does not allow this exploit.

Comment: How to perform that traversal ? *(there’s no `git check-ref-format` however branches are created with libgit2 in ruby)*

Comment: @user2284570 I added a paragraph to my answer: `refs/.[.]/.[.]/.[.]/.[.]/etc/passwd`. I don't know libgit2, so I don't know what kind of output you can make it produce.

Comment: `refs/.[.]/.[.]/.[.]/.[.]/etc/passwd` this is not useful as the command isn’t run as root. In the meantime, a refs can only contains a sha1.

Comment: @user2284570 `/etc/passwd` was just an example to illustrate that you can escape to the parent directory. If you have additional constraints, please mention them in your question. I don't have a crystal ball, I can't help you with problems that you don't disclose. If finding what validation is actually applied is part of your problem, I'm afraid this is something you'll have to do, by trail and error, and guesswork.